# How can i get data and store from fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android

[Frgament 1 in viewpager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EX1i.jpg)

[Fragment 2 in viewpager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd8Il.jpg)

[Fragment 3 in viewpager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRPuj.jpg)

I want get data from individual fragment in viewpager but how can i handle it? In one activity and 3 fragment from viewpager and i wonder how make noswipeviewpager? and main background picture part never change only input layer
and when the use terminates app info of app have to save it's data..

Answer (score 0):

> I want get data from individual fragment in viewpager but how can i handle it?

I assume that your are trying to communicate between fragments in your activity. Basically you will have to define an interface in your fragment in which the data is retrieved from and implement that interface in your parent activity. You can take a look at this good example https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

> In one activity and 3 fragment from viewpager and i wonder how make noswipeviewpager? and main background picture part never change only input layer

You can try to set the background of your rootlayot using the `android:background` attribute like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="...">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

*Remember not to set any background for your fragments' background. Its transparent by default, so the background of your rootlayout can be seen.

This should achieve the purpose of a static background and only the "pages" of your viewpager will appear as swiping above it.

> when the use terminates app info of app have to save it's data..

well you can override the `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` methods in your activity and define your logic in it. You can have a good look at the android activity lifecycle https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle and override the methods as per your need.